# Test method on object before it is called

Tags: php, magento2

I have arrays of employee ID's ($employees). In the case that all of these ID's match to an existing employee, the employees are all rendered successfully by the below code:

```
 foreach($employees as $employee){
  echo $block->addChild(
        'employee' . $employee,
        \Blackbird\ContentManager\Block\Content\Widget\View::class,
        ['content_id' => $employee]
    )->toHtml();
 }
```

If an employee has been deleted, the code will trigger an error:

"Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getContentType() on null [...]"

I'm trying to determine how to test if that error will occur before actually executing the code for the problematic ID.

(This is in Magento 2, but my question isn't particular to Magento)

Any help or nudges in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you don't have a getContentType in your code sample, where is that call?  Is that being called on `$employee`?

Comment: It's in the \Blackbird\ContentManager\Block\Content\Widget\View class

Comment: If you are throwing unknown objects at a a library routine, then the problem is in the code generating the objects.

Comment: The code generating the objects is from a Magento module. Just wondering if I could write in some kind of test/check